# How to assign existing objects to has_many relation with Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have such a relations between models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :documents, :as=>:documentable
   accept_nested_attributes_for :documents
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :documentable, :polymorphic=>true
end
```

I have a set of documents already generated, those have `documentable_type` and `documentable_id` to `NULL`, suppose their ids are 1 and 2

Now i want to create a new post with existing documents, i generated the hash like this.

`h = {:post=>{:title=>'Post Title', :documents_attributes=>{"0"=>{:id=>1},"2"=>{:id=>2}}}}`

and then create the post like `@post = Post.new(h[:post])`

But after ward it goes for finding the `documents` with `documentable_type='Post'` and `documentable_id=NULL` which it can not found.

What would be the proper way to generate hash for such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue by this hash:

```
h = {:post=>{:title=>'Post Title', :document_ids=>{1,2}}}
```